# Java: Calling a stored procedure in an oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

**EDIT: While some of the answers in this question may help others with different problems, the solution was actually related to some bug with the auto-commit feature on a database connection! Forcing a commit after executing the query caused the database to reflect the changes, thus the code shown below IS the correct way to call a stored procedure of this type**

I'm trying to call a simple stored procedure in an oracle database.

The procedure looks like this:

```
procedure clear_orderProcDtlByOrdId(p_order_id in order_header.order_id%type,
                                    p_transaction_id in sl_order_processing_dtl.transaction_id%type DEFAULT NULL,
                                    p_item_action_id in sl_order_processing_dtl.item_action_id%type DEFAULT NULL )
...
```

The java code I'm having trouble with looks like this

```
    try 
    {
        CallableStatement storedProc = conn.prepareCall("{call PKG_PI_FRAUD.clear_orderProcDtlByOrdId(?)}");
        storedProc.setString(1, orderID);
        storedProc.execute();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm not receiving any errors at all, however there are no database changes being reflected. When I run the procedure in SQL Developer I see results. I thought it might be because of a commit issue, but the connection I have established is in auto-commit mode.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is orderID set to VARCHAR in the DB ?

Comment: @PremGenError orderID is a VARCHAR2 in the DB

Comment: Try putting quotes around the parameter then on line 2: storedProc.setString("1", "orderID");

Comment: @twoleggedhorse this causes an `PLS-00707: unsupported construct or internal error [2603]`

Comment: @user2076524 Do you still get the error if you remove the quotes from the parameter name? storedProc.setString("1", orderID);

Comment: @twoleggedhorse yeah, I do

Comment: @user2076524 Is the variable orderID a string? If not try storedProc.setString(1, Integer.toString(orderID)); or similar...

Comment: @twoleggedhorse So it turns out even though I'm 100% sure the connection is in auto-commit mode, I needed to call conn.commit() for the changes to be reflected. STRANGE! Since I can't answer this question due to the fact that I'm a brand new user, if you could post this as an answer that would be awesome :)

Comment: @user2076524: have you executed `commit`  in the `procedure` itself ?

Comment: `conn` and `storedProc` are not closed automatically either with try-with-resources or explicitly in finally block by calling `close()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While some of the answers in this question may help others with different problems, the solution was actually related to some bug with the auto-commit feature on a database connection! Forcing a commit after executing the query caused the database to reflect the changes, thus the code shown in the question IS the correct way to call a stored procedure of this type!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to capture the return of procedure in Oracle database, try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, db_user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to database");

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date now = new java.sql.Date(simpleDateFormat.parse("12/02/2001").getTime());

            String command = "{call SALDOS(?,?)}";
            CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(command);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.DECIMAL);

            cstmt.setDate(1, now);
            cstmt.execute();
            Double str = cstmt.getDouble(2);

            cstmt.close();
            System.out.println("Retorno: " + str);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you use a different Returns Map SimpleJdbcCall this way:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall call = Util.getSimpleJdbcCallInstance();
    call.setProcedureName("PROCED_CONDOMINIAL");
    call.declareParameters(
            new SqlParameter("CONDOMINIO", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("BLOCO", Types.VARCHAR),,
            new SqlOutParameter("P_NUMERO", Types.NUMERIC),
            new SqlOutParameter("P_LOG", Types.VARCHAR));

    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametros.put("CONDOMINIO_IC", descricaoCondominio);
    parametros.put("BLOCO_IC", imovelCondominial.getBloco());

    Map<String, Object> out = call.execute(parametros);
    BigDecimal chave = (BigDecimal) out.get("P_NUMERO");
    imovelCondominial.setId(chave.longValue());
```

and the declaration of the procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE         PROCED_CONDOMINIAL
               (CONDOMINIO            VARCHAR2,
                BLOCO                 VARCHAR2,
                NUMERO                OUT NUMBER,
                LOG                   OUT VARCHAR2)      -- PARAMETROS DE SAIDAS (OUT).-
```

Worked here. Look at this blog.

http://jameajudo.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/call-procedure-oracle-with-java-and.html

Tested on Oracle 10xe and 11xe.